# SSRS Multivalue Parameter in Dataset Query issue

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I Have an embedded dataset in my report which I pass parameters into.

This works fine for a single select using the = Sign in my And line
I would of thought and google results seem to be saying the same that i can just change the = sign to 'IN'

```
FROM [database].[dbo].[itemTable]
 right Outer Join [database].[dbo].[CategoryTable]
  on  [database].[dbo].[itemTable].Category= [database].[dbo].[CategoryTable].Category And ([database].[dbo].[itemTable].Region = @pRegion) And ([database].[dbo].[itemTable].CategoryLN = @pCategoryLN )
where [database].[dbo].[CategoryTable].Category != 'RETIRED'
```

Above works fine but if I change to

```
[database].[dbo].[itemTable].Region IN @pRegion'
```

The query window says Incorrect syntax near '@pRegion'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you are missing is **brackets** around the parameter.

```
[database].[dbo].[itemTable].Region IN (@pRegion)
```

Also make sure you don't edit/parse the parameter values.

Comment: doh! :) thanks mate well im glad it was some thing i understand!

Answer (score 1):

We've resolved this issue by using a database table-valued function (probably found somewhere on the internet, but I can't remember where)

```
    CREATE FUNCTION [database].[dbo].[ParamSplit]
    (
      @List nvarchar(max), -- string returned from multivalue report parameter
      @SplitOn nvarchar(5) -- separator character
    )  
    RETURNS @RtnValue table 
    (

      Id int identity(1,1),
      Value nvarchar(100)
    ) 
    AS  
    BEGIN
      While (Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)>0)
      Begin 
        Insert Into @RtnValue (value)
        Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(Substring(@List,1,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)-1))) 
        Set @List = Substring(@List,Charindex(@SplitOn,@List)+len(@SplitOn),len(@List))
      End 

      Insert Into @RtnValue (Value)
        Select Value = ltrim(rtrim(@List))
      Return
    END
```

Then you can use it in your dataset query.

```
where [database].[dbo].[itemTable].Region IN  (Select [dbo].[ParamSplit].[Value] from [database].[dbo].[ParamSplit](@pRegion,','))
```